# How can I relate entities with ManyToMany (Symfony)?

Tags: symfony, oop, many-to-many, entity

In the entity `products` I am relating my products to my productgroup:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Productgroup")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productgroup", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $productgroup;
```

This i working well.

So for example this is the result:

```
Product      Productgroup

Frog         Animal
Fish         Animal
Pizza        Food
```

But sometimes my products have multiple productgroups like this:

```
Frog         Animal
Fish         Animal, Food
Pizza        Food
```

So I changed my entity to this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Productgroup")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productgroup", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $productgroup;

  public function getProductgroup(): ?Productgroup
    {
      return $this->productgroup;
    }

    public function setProductgroup(?Productgroup $productgroup): self
    {
      $this->productgroup = $productgroup;

      return $this;
    }
```

Now I get the error message:

> Return value of App\Entity\Products::getProductgroup() must be an
>   instance of App\Entity\Productgroup or null, instance of
>   Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner storage for collection of related entities is `PersistentCollection` in your case.

So, property `productgroup` is not a `ProductGroup` entity. It is **collection of `ProductGroup` entities**. For simplicity you can consider it like "array of items".

According to said above, your `getProductgroup` does not return instance of `ProductGroup`, it returns **collection of `ProductGroup`s**, that's why this method should be rewritten as:

```
// no typehint here
// Of course you can use `PersistentCollection` typehint, it is your choice
// main point that returned value is NOT a `ProductGroup` instance
public function getProductgroup()
{
    return $this->productgroup;
}
```

Second, as property `productgroup` is not a `ProductGroup`, your `setProductgroup` method should be rewritten too:

```
// I omit typehint as you pass not instance of `Productgroup`, but `collection`
public function setProductgroup($productgroup): self
{
    $this->productgroup = $productgroup;

    return $this;
}
```

Usually, to add one instance of `Productgroup` to collection, there should be an `adder` method:

```
// here, you can typehint argument, because it is useless 
// to pass anything else except `Productgroup` instance
public function addProductgroup(Productgroup $productgroup): self
{
    $this->productgroup[] = $productgroup;

    return $this;
}
```

Also, it is a good point to init `$this->productgroup` as empty collection in constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->productgroup = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Some [other info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410665/doctrine-manytomany-return-persistentcollection-instead-of-arraycollection) about `PersistentCollection` and `ArrayCollection`.

Comment: Thank you, I tested your suggestion. I do not have an error message anymore. But I do not see in the mySQL database where they are actually connected.

Comment: If it is ManyToMany relation there should be a so called `pivot` table `product_product_group` or similar. Of course if you updated db schema or created a migration using changes in your models.